# How to store array or record in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Anyone please tell me how to store n x n matrix data into SQL Server 2008?

I want to store thousand of pieces of data into SQL Server at the same time from my ASP.NET page so if I pass an array of row and column then how can I store at the same time in SQL Server

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read up about Table-Valued Parameters on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.100).aspx). This might help you if your n x n matrix will always be the same dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server is a **relational database**, data should at [least in 3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). This means that attributes **can't be multivaluates**. To store data as you required you have several options:

- Normalize data and store it in tables.
- Store data array as an [XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx) field.
- Move to NOSQL DBMS or any that supports [multivalue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiValue).

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a stored procedure and pass a DataTable as a parameter to the stored procedure. In your procedure you can then execute a INSERT statement with the data from your DataTable. All you have to do is create and fill your DataTable before you execute the stored procedure.

Here is a link on how to do that. It's written in C# I figured since you're talking about ASP.net this might be it for you.. it should also be easy enough to translate the snippet in VB.net if that's what you're using.
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/214492/Passing-a-datatable-to-a-stored-procedure-in-Sql-S